# Combing sql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

Query one:

```
"SELECT `id` FROM `$amxadmins` WHERE `steamid` = '$logged[username]'"
```

Query two:

```
"SELECT `admin_id` FROM `$admins_servers` WHERE `admin_id` = 'ID FROM QUERY ONE' AND `server_id` = '$serverf[id]'"
```

Can you help me with combining them ?

Comment: Is it SQL Server or what ??

Comment: It's look like a mix of SQL and PHP. What SQL vendor are you using? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Comment: @ZoffDino MySQL and PHP

Comment: Why do you even need the outer select if you're just getting the `admin_id` that you already know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the first sql statement into the second one:

```
SELECT `admin_id`
FROM `$admins_servers`
WHERE `admin_id` = 
    ( SELECT `id`
      FROM `$amxadmins`
      WHERE `steamid` = '$logged[username]'
    )
AND `server_id` = '$serverf[id]'
```

I guess there is just one `admin_id`. If not, you need `in` instead of `=`:

```
WHERE `admin_id` in 
    ( ...
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with a simple inner join:

```
SELECT `$admins_servers.admin_id` 
 FROM `$amxadmins` 
   INNER JOIN `$admins_servers` 
   ON `$amxadmins.id = `$admins_servers.admin_id` 
 WHERE `server_id` = '$serverf[id]' 
 AND `steamid` = '$logged[username]'
```